# Live feed from a flatbed scanner?

Tags: graphics

Would it be possible to write some kind of software that would allow you to see a live feed from the CCD sensor of a flatbed scanner as the mirror moves across the bed? Is there software that exists which can do this? I've had a hard time searching for this, as I'm not even sure how to word this question.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt it's possible without hacking the firmware since the standard scanner<->host protocols (e.g. [TWAIN](https://twain.org/) or [WIA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/image/windows-image-acquisition-drivers)) only provide whole images (AFAIK).